# Cannot validate against multiple xsd schemas in C#

Tags: c#, xml, validation, schema

I wanna verify a digitally signed xml against its schema definition while this schema actually contains this tag

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" id="schema"/>
```

Then I tried to load schemas:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Schemas.Add(null, "a.xsd");
settings.Schemas.Compile();
```

I will get the following error
The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature' element is not declared.

Comment: Does your XML validate in a tool like XmlSpy?

If I recall correctly you should be able to validate against imported/included schemas using the XmlReader..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also load in the imported schema with another

settings.Schemas.Add(`[importednamespace]`, `[pathtoimportedXSD]`);

Answer (score 2):

The scheme xmldsig-core-schema.xsd does not charge for security reasons since it makes reference to a DTD to validate the upload directory and add it as another scheme.

```
<!DOCTYPE schema PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XMLSchema 200102//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd"
```

this works
The solution is C#

```
XElement xsdMarkup = XElement.Load("C:\\Proyectos\\WindowService\\Sbif\\Schema\\Schema\\IndicadoresFinancieros-v1.0.xsd");

XElement xsdMarkup2 = XElement.Load("http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd");

XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();

schemas.Add(null, xsdMarkup.CreateReader());
schemas.Add(null, xsdMarkup2.CreateReader());

schemas.Compile();
```

Comment: `Add(null, reader)` instead of just `Add(reader)` was the crucial change for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

are you sure hash is required at the end of?:
http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#

Comment: It is part of the namespace URI, see http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd

Answer (score 0):

From the error it would seem the XML Signature schema is not being loaded, despite the import.

Adding the XML Signature schema to the schema set explicitly should confirm that.

The most likely cause is the schema set's `XmlReslver` is not finding the file you specify, this could be a current folder/relative path issue.

Using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896645) to see where you could is trying to load the XSD file may also help.